# Kendo StockChart Navigator not updating chart when adjusted

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have the following which displays the chart, however when I adjust the handles on the navigator the chart doesn't adjust to display the points for the selected period.

This is my Razor code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().StockChart<Portal.Models.Company.StockDataPoint>(Model.StockPricePerformance)
  .Name("stockChart")
  .DateField("Date")
  .Series(series =>
  {
      series.Line(s => s.ClosingPrice)
          .Markers(false);
  })
  .CategoryAxis(axis =>
  {
      axis.Categories(model => model.Date).Type(ChartCategoryAxisType.Category)
          .MajorGridLines(lines => lines.Visible(false))
          .Axis.BaseUnit = ChartAxisBaseUnit.Months;
      axis.Labels(label => label.Step(24).Rotation(-60).Format("dd MMM yy"));
      axis.Axis.BaseUnitStep = 10;
  })
  .Navigator(nav =>
  {
      nav.Series(series => series.Area(data => data.ClosingPrice));
      nav.DateField("Date");
      nav.AutoBind(true);

  })
  .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip
      .Visible(true)
      .Template("#= dataItem.ClosingPrice # [#=dataItem.Date#]")
  )
)
```

This is what the chart looks like:

[image: Stock chart screen capture]

As you can see the chart hasn't been redrawn or adjusted to only show the points for the chosen period. I had a look at the Telerik examples and API reference but I couldn't work out what options would make the navigator work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out.

Instead of using `axis.Categories(model => model.Date).Type(ChartCategoryAxisType.Category)` I used  `axis.Axis.BaseUnit = ChartAxisBaseUnit.Days;` in the `CategoryAxis` part of the chart definition.

For my chart this was enough for the chart to show all points (no aggregation) and allow the navigator to work without any extra work.